# Shopify API GraphQL get multiple image thumbnails in single request

Tags: axios, graphql, shopify

I'm working with the Shopify API using graphql, We've been tasked to implement srcset images to speed up page load times, however I'm having trouble generating a query which will pull multiple size urls.

```
query ($tag: String!) {
  products(first: 10, query: $tag) {
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        tags
        handle
        images(first:1, maxWidth:360) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

this query works at pulling in a single image url with a max width of 360px, however if I do something similar to the below (which I would hope would generate a url for a 360px image and a 720px image, then I get the error  `"message": "Field 'images' has an argument conflict: {first:\"1\",maxWidth:\"360\"} or {first:\"1\",maxWidth:\"720\"}?",`

```
query ($tag: String!) {
  products(first: 10, query: $tag) {
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        tags
        handle
        images(first:1, maxWidth:360) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        images(first:1, maxWidth:720) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
              __typename
            }
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

Any advice on how I can structure my query so it pulls in two different size thumbnails?

Thanks!

Comment: use aliases, read docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @xadm mentioned you can use aliases:

```
        small_image: images(first:1, maxWidth:360) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
            }
          }
        }
        large_image: images(first:1, maxWidth:720) {
          edges {
            node {
              src
            }
          }
        }
```

You add just some names before the `images` call of your choice.

But your approach is **deprecated**, you should use `transformedSrc` instead.

So it will become:

```
        images(first:1) {
          edges {
            node {
              originalSrc
              large: transformedSrc(maxWidth: 720)
              small: transformedSrc(maxWidth: 360)
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Correct ... but note that as of Mar 2022, transformedSrc is deprecated in favor of url.  Thus, the first works but is deprecated in favor of the second:

```
        smallA: transformedSrc(maxWidth: 64)

        smallB: url(transform: {maxWidth: 64})
```